# How to get image-based lettering

Tags: xetex, luatex, metapost, context-lmtx

[image]

How can we get this effect in LaTex/ConTeXt?

Comment: Try *TikZ* and its pattern library

Comment: Hi, are you sure LaTeX/ConTeXt is the right tool? GIMP/Inkscape are probably better...

Comment: Thank you very much for your enthusiasm.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you are using the same image for each letter. This can be accomplished with the Ti*k*Z `fadings` library together with `tikzfadingfrompicture` and `scope fading`. For the image file cherries.jpg I just selected something from a "cherry tree" image search.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\renewcommand*\sfdefault{ugq}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\letterimage}[1]{
    \foreach \S[count=\n] in {#1}{%
        \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=cherries\n]
            \node [text=transparent!0, font=\sffamily, scale=6]{\S};
        \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[scope fading=cherries\n]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{cherries.jpg}};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
}

\begin{document}
\letterimage{C,H,A,R,M}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow...Wonderful suggestion

Comment: Thank you very much for your enthusiasm, this is exactly the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

You can do this without loading *any* packages.

The following works with Plain pdfTeX, Plain LuaTeX, pdfLaTeX, and LuaLaTeX:

```tex
\catcode`\@=11

\ifdefined\directlua
    \def\pdfliteral{\pdfextension literal}
    \def\pdfrestore{\pdfextension restore\relax}
    \def\pdfsave{\pdfextension save\relax}
    \let\pdflastxform=\lastsavedboxresourceindex
    \let\pdflastximage=\lastsavedimageresourceindex
    \let\pdfpageheight=\pageheight
    \let\pdfpagewidth=\pagewidth
    \let\pdfrefxform=\useboxresource
    \let\pdfrefximage=\useimageresource
    \let\pdfxform=\saveboxresource
    \let\pdfximage=\saveimageresource
\fi

\newbox\bg@backgroundbox
\newbox\bg@outbox
\newbox\bg@textbox
\newdimen\bg@textwidth
\newdimen\bg@textheight

\protected\def\background#1#2{%
    \setbox\bg@textbox=\hbox{#1}%
    \bg@textwidth=\wd\bg@textbox%
    \bg@textheight=\ht\bg@textbox%
    \wd\bg@textbox=\z@%
    \ht\bg@textbox=\z@%
    %
    \setbox\bg@backgroundbox=\hbox{#2}%
    \wd\bg@backgroundbox=\pdfpagewidth%
    \ht\bg@backgroundbox=\pdfpageheight%
    \pdfxform\bg@backgroundbox%
    \setbox\bg@backgroundbox=\hbox{\pdfrefxform\pdflastxform}%
    \wd\bg@backgroundbox=\z@%
    \ht\bg@backgroundbox=\z@%
    %
    \setbox\bg@outbox=\hbox{%
        \pdfsave%
        \pdfliteral direct {7 Tr}%
        \box\bg@textbox%
        \pdfsave%
        \pdfliteral direct {0 Tr}%
        \box\bg@backgroundbox%
        \pdfrestore%
        \pdfrestore%
    }%
    \wd\bg@outbox=\bg@textwidth%
    \ht\bg@outbox=\bg@textheight%
    \box\bg@outbox%
}

\protected\def\backgroundimage#1#2{%
    \setbox\bg@textbox=\hbox{#1}%
    \pdfximage width \wd\bg@textbox {#2}%
    \background{#1}{\pdfrefximage\pdflastximage}%
}

\catcode`\@=12

\ifdefined\documentclass
    \documentclass{article}

    \begin{document}
    \Huge\bfseries
        \backgroundimage{CHARM}{NPBT_SC_background.jpg}
    \end{document}
\else
    \nopagenumbers
    \font\tgab=ec-qagb at 72bp\tgab

    \backgroundimage{CHARM}{NPBT_SC_background.jpg}

    \background{CHARM}{%
        \fiverm
        \vbox to 1in{%
            \leaders%
            \vbox{%
                \hbox to \hsize{%
                    \leaders%
                    \hbox{charm}%
                    \hfill%
                }%
            }%
            \vfill%
        }%
    }

    \background{CHARM}{\pdfliteral{
        1 0 0 rg 0 00 360 20 re f
        0 1 0 rg 0 20 360 20 re f
        0 0 1 rg 0 40 360 20 re f
    }}

    \bye
\fi
```

First, we save the drawing commands for the background (in this case the image) into an XObject. Then, we set text rendering mode to "clip" (7), which adds the text outlines to the current clipping path. Finally, we draw the XObject, which is clipped by the text.

The result when compiled with `luatex`:

[image: picture of output]

Comment: Wow...Wonderful.

Answer (score 3):

Since this *was* tagged with [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), I thought you might like a `lualatex` + `luamplib` version.

[image]

To compile this you need to provide a suitable `cherries.png` file, and use `lualatex` as the TeX engine.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
vardef cherry_letter(expr A, fontname) = 
  save g, i; path g[]; numeric i; i = 0;
  for item within glyph ASCII A of fontname:
    g[incr i] = pathpart item scaled 1/8;
  endfor
  image(
    draw TEX("\includegraphics[width=1.6in]{cherries.png}") shifted 10 down;
    clip currentpicture to g1;
    for k=2 upto i:
      fill g[k] withcolor background;
    endfor
  )
enddef;
beginfig(1);
  background := 1/256(180,230,182);
  string s; s = "METAPOST";
  numeric x; x = 0;
  for i=1 upto length s:
    string c; c = substring (i-1, i) of s;
    picture t; t = cherry_letter(c, "phvb8r");
    draw t shifted (x, 0);
    x := x + xpart lrcorner t + if c = "T": 0 else: 12 fi;
  endfor
  picture P; P = currentpicture; currentpicture := nullpicture;
  bboxmargin := 20;
  fill bbox P withcolor background; draw P;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

#### Notes

- You can't use `\includegraphics` with traditional Metapost
- So you need to use `lualatex` for this one.
- See §9.11 of the [Metapost manual](https://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpman.pdf) for details of `glyph`.
- If you have lots of this, you might want to devise a rather smarter kerning procedure.

Comment: very nice ideal